# React/Redux-form re-renders unnecessarily with stateless component BUT NOT with a class

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, redux, redux-form

We have a chat page where the structure is basically, the messages are rendered in one div, then a button and an input form containing a single redux form field are rendered below:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='messages'>
    {thisConversation.messages
      ? thisConversation.messages.map((message, i) =>
        <Message
          key={i}
          myUserId={this.props.userId}
          {...message}
        />)
      : ''}
  </div>
  <div className='send-button'>
    <FlatButton
      label='SEND'
      onClick={() => this.props.submitMessage()}
    />
  </div>
  <InputForm handleSubmit={(e) => this.props.submitMessage(e)} />
</div>
```

We were experiencing performance issues and noticed images and divs in the messages flickering when typing in the form. We looked into it and established using Chrome's paint flashing feature that react was re-rendering all messages on any keypress in the form. This shouldn't have been the case, as the messages were not receiving any new props or changing at all.

Since the `<Message />` component was stateless, we changed it to a class in order to try and solve the problem using `shouldComponentUpdate`. However, as soon as we changed it from a stateless component to a class, React stopped re-rendering it in the same way. Effectively, this solved our problem - we didn't need `shouldComponentUpdate` at all.

I don't understand a) why the error was occurring in the first place and b) why it was solved. Is there any difference in how React treats class components and stateless components in terms of re-rendering?

Comment: Please provide your `mapStateToProps` and reducer code.

Comment: I pass down the whole state to the props of the parent chat element. The input form is connected to the state via redux-form, which has its own reducers under the hood. The actions that are being fired from the form are only redux-form actions - they don't affect any of the reducers in my code.

Comment: Can you show the Message component's implementation before and after the change?